# How to find the maximum value of a list in parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm working with a funtion that takes a combination of values and updates a computed value. If I pass several combinations to that function, it will compute several different values and I want to retain the maximum of all those values. To speed up the process I'm running it **in parallel**.

Simplifying, I have a function that takes the current maximum and updates it (if necessary), given a list. How do I run this function in parallel to speed up the computation, **sharing the value** with all active processes so that the current value is always the maximum? At the end, I want to know that combination/list from a list of combinations that will give me the maximum value.

In this example using the multiprocessing module, the script should return 62 (the maximum value) and instead it sometimes returns 45. What's happening here and what need I change?

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Process
import time

def update_best(numbers, best):
   for n in numbers:
       time.sleep(.1)    # working ...
       if n > best.value:
           best.value = n

nos = [[1.1,2.1,3.1], [62,5.2,4.2], [7.3,8.3,9.3], [3.4,4.4,5.4], [45,4.5,3.5]]

for combo in nos:
   best = Value('f', .42)
   p1 = Process(target=update_best, args=(combo,best,))
   p2 = Process(target=update_best, args=(combo,best,))
   p1.start()
   p2.start()

print("end")
time.sleep(3)
print(f"best = {best.value}")
```

EDIT: the not-parallel version looks like this:

```
def update_best(numbers):
    global best
    for n in numbers:
        time.sleep(.1)
        if n > best:
            best = n

            
nos = [[1.1,2.1,3.1], [62,5.2,4.2], [7.3,8.3,9.3], [3.4,4.4,5.4], [45,4.5,3.5]]
best = .42

for combo in nos:
    update_best(combo)
print("end")
time.sleep(3)
print(f"best = {best}")
```

Comment: can you also paste your 'not parellel' version, for us to easier understand the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually not complex. I would recommend using `multiprocessing.Pool` and its function `map`. Like this:

```py
import os
import multiprocessing as mp 

def partition(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def mymax(vals):
    print(os.getpid(), vals)
    return max(vals)

def pmax(vals):
    with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
        results = pool.map(mymax, partition(vals, 5))
    return max(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = pmax([1.1,2.1,3.1, 62,5.2,4.2, 7.3,8.3,9.3, 3.4,4.4,5.4, 45,4.5,3.5])
    print(m)
```

Output:

```sh
$ python3 pmax.py 
829763 [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 62, 5.2]
829764 [4.2, 7.3, 8.3, 9.3, 3.4]
829765 [4.4, 5.4, 45, 4.5, 3.5]
62
```

**Important:** You MUST use `if __name__ == "__main__":` in your main file. It won't work otherwise.

Explanation:

You cannot share a variable with different processes unless you use some IPC primitives (shared memory, message queue, etc).

However, you can apply divide and conquer to the problem and solve it in two stages:

1. Do stuff in parallel. The main process must wait for all parallel processed before continuing.

   - In this case, you find the maximum of a sub-array
2. Merge those results to produce the final output (this is done in the main process)

   - In this case: Find the **maximum prime** (pun intended) of those intermediate maximums.

Comment: 1) It seems to work with or without the `if __name__ == "__main__":` boilerplate. (I am using jupyterlab.) 2) I implemented a function that sleeps for 2 seconds. I am running Pool(5), i.e. 5 processes. The whole cell takes about 6 seconds. Isn't that stilll a bit much? I thought in parallel it'd be closer to 2 seconds.

Comment: that may depend on the number of partitions. i.e.: processes may have run more than once each.

Comment: ah sorry, 6s is perfectly fine because in the code above it's 3*2s sleeping. any comment on the boilerplate code needed and then not really?

Comment: I don't know about the `if main` thing. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) says the `main` module must be available. I guess my use cases have been a little more complicated than this.