# What is the most time efficient way to calculate the distance between tuples in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, distance

I have a list with tuples:

`tuple_list = [(1,3),(4,7),(8,1),(5,4),(9,3),(7,2),(2,7),(3,1),(8,9),(5,2)]`

From this list, I want to return the minimum distance of two numbers in a tuple.

In the naive approach, I would do the following:

```
distance = 10
for tup in tuple_list:
    if abs(tup[0]-tup[1]) < distance:
        distance = abs(tup[0]-tup[1])
```

Then, in the end, `distance` would equal 1.

However, I suspect there is a faster method to obtain the minimum distance that calculates all the distances in parallel.

Comment: Your algorithm is already O(n) why do you assume there is a faster method? Or do you mean a method that takes less code?

Comment: This is a serial process where the calculations don't depend on each other. Hence, we could parallelize the calculations, I suspect.

Comment: To clarify: in the naive approach, there is a serial dependency. But we should be able to calculate all distances in parallel and then return the minimum value.

Comment: Your code should fail to run, need to change `for tup in range(len(tuple_list)):` to `for tup in tuple_list:`

Comment: `min_tuple = min(lst, key=lambda x: abs(int.__sub__(*x))<distance` and `abs` on `min_tuple`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the maximum value of a list in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881757/how-to-find-the-maximum-value-of-a-list-in-parallel)

Comment: I like list comprehension so **`min([abs(d1-d2) for d1, d2 in tuple_list])`** [complexity should be O(n) like yours, but subtracting only once per tuple helps; you could set `dtup=abs(tup[0]-tup[1])` before *`if dtup<distance: distance=dtup`* to shave a bit of time off of yours aswell]

Comment: @Driftr95: Your code is indeed more elegant, but it is still O(n)

Comment: @Driftr95: Drop the pointless `list` and just use a genexpr (so you don't create a potentially large temporary `list`, you just process the values as they're generated): `min(abs(d1-d2) for d1, d2 in tuple_list)`

Comment: @Emil: The code will *always* be `O(n)`. There's no way to process every element without processing every element. Even parallelizing (something that is mostly useless on CPython), is just applying a constant divisor by the number of threads doing the work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks. I'm never quite sure when it's safe to drop the `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, in the CPython reference interpreter, parallelized computations are pretty useless; [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL) prevents you from gaining meaningful benefit from CPU-bound work like this unless the work can be done by an extension that manually releases the GIL, using non-Python types. `numpy` could gain you *some* benefit (if the data was already in a `numpy` array) by vectorizing (likely to do better than actual parallelization anyway, unless the data is *enormous*), but no matter how you slice it, the general case, for arbitrary data, will be `O(n)`; you can't improve on that in the general case because every item must be considered, so even in ideal circumstances, you're just applying a constant divisor to the work, but it remains `O(n)`.

You can simplify your code a bit, and use constructs that are better optimized in CPython, e.g.

```
distance = min(abs(d1 - d2) for d1, d2 in tuple_list)
```

which will compute `abs(d1 - d2)` only once per loop, and potentially save a little overhead over the plain `for` loop + `if` check (plus, it'll remove the need to come up with an initializer for `distance` that's definitely larger than the minimum that should replace it), but it's still `O(n)`, it's just simpler code with some minor micro-optimizations.

In some special cases you could improve on this though. If you must regularly modify the `list`, and must be able to quickly determine the smallest difference at any given point in time, you *could* [use a heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) with precomputed differences. Adding a new item, or removing the minimum item, in the heap would be `O(log n)` (constructing the heap in the first place being `O(n)`), and getting the current smallest item would be `O(1)` (it's always in index `0`).

Constructing the heap in the first place:

```
import heapq

tuple_list = [(1,3),(4,7),(8,1),(5,4),(9,3),(7,2),(2,7),(3,1),(8,9),(5,2)]
tuple_heap = [(abs(a - b), (a, b)) for a, b in tuple_list]  # O(n) work
heapq.heapify(tuple_heap)  # O(n) work; tuple_heap.sort() would also work,
                           # but it would be O(n log n)
```

Adding a new item (where `x` and `y` are the items to add):

```
heapq.heappush(tuple_heap, (abs(x - y), (x, y)))  # O(log n)
```

Popping off the current smallest item:

```
diff, tup = heapq.heappop(tuple_heap)  # O(log n)
# Or to unpack values:
diff, (x, y) = heapq.heappop(tuple_heap)  # O(log n)
```

Getting values from current smallest item (without removing it):

```
diff, tup = tuple_heap[0]  # O(1)
# Or to unpack values:
diff, (x, y) = tuple_heap[0]  # O(1)
```

Obviously, this only make sense if you regularly need the current minimum item, and the set of things to consider is constantly changing, but it's one of the few cases where you can get better than `O(n)` performance in common cases, without paying more than `O(n)` costs in setup costs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can optimise this would be using multi-threaded solution, and calculating the tuple-distance for each tuple in a thread, you'll see probably a time advantage for large lists, but still, in terms of complexity it will be the same `O(n)`. Since the solution you provided is already the most optimal, it has already a time complexity of `O(n)`, and there isn't a more optimal approach to find a minimum in a list than `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you, I realize that. Indeed I was thinking about a multi-threaded solution. However, based on the comment from @ShadowRanger, I realize it is not going to be faster, even when being multi-threaded.